# Add bar into all master pages

Tags: sapui5

I have a SplitApp based on this boilerplate http://goo.gl/zwNeH6
I have many master pages and many detail pages.
How I can add the same elementa (form example a personal bar) into all master pages without duplicate the XML-view code and JS-controller code?

I add the pages by this code:

```
function addDetailAndMaster(){
    var splitApp = sap.ui.getCore().byId("splitApp");



    //master
    splitApp.addMasterPage(sap.ui.xmlview("IntraMaster", "apps.appIntra.master.IntraMaster"));
        splitApp.addMasterPage(sap.ui.xmlview("intraAcqMaster", "apps.appIntra.master.intraAcqMaster"));
        splitApp.addMasterPage(sap.ui.xmlview("intraCesMaster", "apps.appIntra.master.intraCesMaster"));
            splitApp.addMasterPage(sap.ui.xmlview("segnIncrMaster", "apps.appIntra.master.segnIncrMaster"));
            splitApp.addMasterPage(sap.ui.xmlview("presMaster", "apps.appIntra.master.presMaster"));
            splitApp.addMasterPage(sap.ui.xmlview("dettMaster", "apps.appIntra.master.dettMaster"));

    //detail    
    splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("welcomeIntraDetail", "apps.appIntra.misc.welcomeIntraDetail"));  
        splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("advancedDetail", "apps.appIntra.detail.advancedDetail"));
        splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("storeProcedureDetail", "apps.appIntra.detail.storeProcedureDetail"));
            splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("operationDetail", "apps.appIntra.detail.operationDetail"));
            splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("rowDetail", "apps.appIntra.detail.rowDetail"));
            splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("rowDetailEdit", "apps.appIntra.detail.rowDetailEdit"));
                splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("artSnzNomDetail", "apps.appIntra.detail.artSnzNomDetail"));
                splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("formNewNomDogDetail", "apps.appIntra.detail.form.formNewNomDogDetail"));
                    splitApp.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("rowArtConNomDetail", "apps.appIntra.detail.rowArtConNomDetail"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As there's no API available to achieve what you have asked (checking the [API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitApp.html)), you can try this approach,

1)  Get all the master pages (also works for detail pages) of the `SplitApp`

`var aMasterPages = splitApp.getMasterPages();`

2) Loop through them and add the content that you need

```
for(var i=0; i<aMasterPages.length; i++)
{
  var oMasterPage = aMasterPages[i];

  /* Add header content */
  var oBar = new sap.m.Bar({contentMiddle: new sap.m.Label({text: "Title"}) });
  oMasterPage.addHeaderContent(oBar);

}
```

Similarly, 'addContent' method can be used to add any other content to the page.
Go through the API reference I've mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

Create you personal bar as a separate View-Controller pair and instantiate it from all your pages. A View-Controller does not neccessarily have to be a Page it can be anything no matter how trivial or fine-grained you wanna go.

If you don't have specific controller code you could indeed use fragments like qualiture already suggested.